# Error System.NotSupportedException on Razor Pages Project

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, razor-pages

After researching a lot and finding nothing about it, I decided to ask for collaboration here in the community.

I am trying to perform run in Visual Studio 2019 from a Razor Pages project, created in the 2017 version of Visual Studio. The Target Framework is net461.

However, the following error occurs:

> NotSupportedException: Attempting to load an assembly from a network
>   location that would cause the assembly to be in safe mode in earlier
>   versions of the .NET Framework. This version of the .NET Framework
>   does not enable CAS policy by default, so this loading can be
>   dangerous. If it does not intend to confine the assembly, enable the
>   loadFromRemoteSources option.

I am not loading any assemblies over the network. All files are on my computer. Also, all exe, dll files are unlocked.

Error is in the startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc()
```

I greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

are you creating .NET 4.6.* project or .Net Core? For .Net Core the target framework should be `.NET Core 2.* or 3.*` and make sure SDK is installed on your machine.